# In KDE 4.11.2 saucy with both nvidia and nouveau drivers I have strange artefacts

Tags: nvidia, kde, kwin

KDE 4.11.2, ubuntu 13.10, nvidia/nouveau, system/raster qt graphics system.
When opening/closing a window there is a chance, that black blinking line will appear near plasma panel. Also  when a popup like this one:

[image: artefacts image]

disappears, it doesn't disappear at once, but also blinks (appears/disappears quickly). 
What can be done in order to solve this problem?

Comment: I also tried starting kde with cleared ~/, but it didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try disabling Blur in System Settings / Desktop Effects / All Effects in the Appearance section. It fixed it for me. Hope it works for you as well.

I use nvidia drivers 331.20, mint 13 (based on precise LTS) with KDE 4.12.0.

Comment: It works. Actually, there is another way - to disable "Сохранять промежуточные результаты рендеринга" in Blur settings. Not sure, how is it in English, but it is the inly enableable/disableable function there.